# Bootstrap inline form search bar width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem:** The search box does not change size when resizing the page. I also need to make it wider, but I really can't seem how to do it, I have tried adding styles to the box such as *width: 100%;* Nothing seems to work

Also, you can see in the image linked below, that the select drop down box is slightly clipped off on the right hand side. I don't know what is causing this, so I don't know how to go about fixing it.

I also need to make the form fill the width of the row. ***Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!***

[Image of Form](https://i.gyazo.com/3b3a6168e0499e335c4e9ed11e20e148.png)

[How i want it too look](https://s11.postimg.org/3yebndn9f/ddsddsd.png)

**Code:**

```
<header>
      <div class="container">
        <form action="search.php" method="get" data-toggle="validator" role="form" class="form-inline">
          <div class="row">
            <h2>Enter a username and choose a category to search in</h2>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search a username here" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="selectpicker form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Catagory</option>
                    <option value="volvo">Minecraft username</option>
                    <option value="saab">Minecraft UUID</option>
                    <option value="mercedes">Mc-Market username</option>
                    <option value="audi">Skype username</option>
                  </select>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                </div><!-- /form-group -->
              </div><!-- /input-group -->
          </div>  <!-- /row-group -->
        </form><!-- /form-group -->
      </div><!-- /container-group -->
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Don't mix with other components
>
> Do not mix form groups or grid column classes directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input
>   group inside of the form group or grid-related element.

See [input-groups docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). `Input-group`s should be nested within `form-group`s and you haven't fully applied the correct markup for your button. It should be within `<span class="input-group-btn">`.

**Note**: from the docs,

> *Avoid using `<select>` elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.*

**Working Example:** *Open using FullPage*

```css
header {
  background-color: #42f4c2;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container text-center">

    <h2>Enter a username and choose a category to search in</h2>

    <form action="search.php" method="get" data-toggle="validator" role="form" class="form-inline">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search a username here" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <select class="selectpicker form-control" required>
            <option value="">Catagory</option>
            <option value="volvo">Minecraft username</option>
            <option value="saab">Minecraft UUID</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mc-Market username</option>
            <option value="audi">Skype username</option>
          </select>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-search">Search</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! That was a really nice and well explained answer. Thank you!